# Counting the number of "permitted" pairings between two sets

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, matching-theory

Suppose I have two sets $A$ and $B$. We will be considering pairs of elements $(a,b)$, where $a\in A$ and $b \in B$. I have a function $f(a,b) \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, i.e. for each pair I can say whether it is "allowed" or not. Given the complete output of $f$, i.e. the list of all allowed pairs, I want to determine the maximum number of *mutally* allowed pairings that can be achieved. By *mutually allowed* I mean that elements of $A$ and $B$ may only appear once in a set of *mutually allowed* pairs.

Here's a simple example in the form of a table:

|  | a0 | a1 | a2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b0 | X | X |  |
| b1 |  | X |  |
| b2 |  | X | X |

i.e. this is the output of my function $f$. So the indices of the allowed pairs are (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), and (2,2). In this case it is fairly intuitive to see that the maximum number of simultaneous pairs is achieved by (1,1),(2,2),(3,3), so the answer is 3. But I am not sure about the general case.

It feels like there is probably some matrix voodoo that can be done to solve this problem efficiently. I am hoping it can be done with better than combinatoric complexity, which I think is what you get if you try to just check all the possible sets of mutually-allowed pairings and see which is largest.

Comment: Your problem is better known as finding a maximum size matching in a bipartite graph. The Hopcroft-Karp algorithm has worst-case time complexity $O(m\sqrt{n})$ where $n=|A|+|B|$ and $m$ is the number of pairs with $f(a,b)=1$. In particular it's $O(n^{3/2})$.

Comment: Amazing, thanks!

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe, is there a lower bound for this problem, i.e., is Hopcroft-Karp known to be optimal?

Comment: @kodlu, I don’t know any lower bounds but I’m not an expert. Apparently there’s a 2020 FOCS paper claiming (up to logarithmic factors) $O(m+n\sqrt n)$. That algorithm seems complicated though.